# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Wifi Doesn't work until I press Suspend and Resume

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, suspend

When I boot up my laptop running Ubuntu and log in to my user account, the wifi does not connect.
When I click the wifi icon in the top right, all the options are disabled except from VPN Connections.

When I suspend and then resume the laptop, the wifi connects and everything works as it should.

Edit:

lspci -nn | grep 0280 Output :

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Hi I have experienced the same, after wireless disappeared, What worked for me was to go to the VPN option, it shows your last connected networks, select the one you want - DON'T edit - close, and it reconnect, next time it connects as usual.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, been using my Windows laptop for a while.

Still having the same issue after trying your method Ken, I've updated my question for @Fabby

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Could you now: reboot, log in, press [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lsmod | grep --ignoce-case rtl` and then do a `modprobe rtlxxxx` (replace the xxxx with the output of the `lsmod` command above) and verify that that brings WiFi on-line? If unsure, just post the output of the `lsmod` command and I'll figure it out for you!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately the lsmod command isn't actually ouputting anything, no errors or anything. Screenshot of terminal http://i.imgur.com/gFUea3d.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research into the issue, I finally managed to find a solution to this problem, it's a known Ubuntu bug and here is the [workaround](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558).

Thanks for everyones help

~  Sean